# Is there a way to configure the ClientBuilder POST request that would enable it to return code in JSON format?

Tags: java, jax-rs

```
String Json_ = "{\"CQ\":^ttest^”,\"Time\":\"2022-01-23\"}";
final Response response = 
ClientBuilder.newClient().target(url).request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.entity(Json_, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Response.class);
final int responsecode = response.getStatus();
String actual = response.readEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(actual);
```

I am trying to post the CQ and time to the https link i have but the response i get is 500. Could anyone please tell if there is any mistake in my piece of code
The curl works for posting the data to the url

curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"CQ":"ttest","SchedulingTime":"2021-01-30T08:30:00Z"}' http://urlpath -i -s .

Comment: One difference I can see id the "SchedulingTime/Time" difference

Comment: And the `^`.....

Comment: HTTP 500 is an error on the server side - has nothing to do with ClientBuilder configuration.

Comment: i was able to fix it after changing the Schedule time and the responsecode returned 200. Thank you

Comment: String jsonobject = "{\"CQ\": + ${cQ.getCQ(),\"SchedulingTime\": + ${cQ.getScheduleTime()}},\"ClientType\":\"n\"}";